# Import Box2D : file not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, include, box2d

I'm trying to import Box2D library but I have a compilation error : 'Box2D/Box2D.h' file not found.

I tried lots of things to solve this problem but without any success. I'm not using cocos2d so I don't have any templates.
I just drag and drop Box2D folder in my Xcode project (tried to check and uncheck the 'copy to destination folder).

Tried to check 'Always Search User Path' etc ... No success.

If someone has the solution : god bless you !

Comment: I know it might probably not be this... but isn't it Box2D/Box2D.h, not Box2D/Bow2D.h ? or did you just make a typo when copying it here?

Comment: Sorry it's juste typo error Edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop the Box2D.h/Bow2D.h to your project.If it is not as simple as that, I can recommend you this [tutorial](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/setup-ios) which explain everything you need to know to set up Box 2D in XCode.

**EDIT**

I have just tried the project in the tut I referenced and i believe you didn't set-up your header search path.  Box2D files are intended to be included like this: #include  so you need to go to **Build Settings** then add an entry for the Debug and Release key of the **Header Search Paths** (under **Build Settings**)

you are looking as something like this: `Debug    Box2D_v2.1.2/Box2D`

Comment: Check how they set-up the Header Search Paths in the project setting - that is probably where you are experimenting some difficulties

Comment: Yeah I think it's that point I'm missing but I doing exactly the same

Comment: There is a link to the source code of the project they did in the tut I referenced. Try this project to identify your issue if you haven't already